# java.lang.ClassCastException when maximize mpart

Tags: exception, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a Eclipse E4 application with some different MParts. Now when I maximize the MPart by double clicking on its tab I got the ClassCastException. Also when I minimize it again, the same exception will be thrown. I looked at the error but could't find a place in my source where this exception can be thrown. Can someone help me with this? Below you can find the full stack trace of the error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(FillLayout.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(FillLayout.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.LayoutComposite.computeSize(LayoutComposite.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.controlComputeSize(SizeCache.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.computeMinimumWidth(SizeCache.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.computeSize(SizeCache.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite$ExpandableLayout.computeSize(ExpandableComposite.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite.computeSize(ExpandableComposite.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData.computeSize(FillData.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(FillLayout.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(FillLayout.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData.computeSize(FillData.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(FillLayout.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(FillLayout.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.LayoutComposite.computeSize(LayoutComposite.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.controlComputeSize(SizeCache.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.computeMinimumWidth(SizeCache.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.computeSize(SizeCache.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Form$FormLayout.computeSize(Form.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Form.computeSize(Form.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.controlComputeSize(SizeCache.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SizeCache.computeSize(SizeCache.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SharedScrolledComposite.reflow(SharedScrolledComposite.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SharedScrolledComposite.scheduleReflow(SharedScrolledComposite.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SharedScrolledComposite.access$1(SharedScrolledComposite.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.SharedScrolledComposite$1.handleEvent(SharedScrolledComposite.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_SIZE(Control.java:5459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.WM_SIZE(Scrollable.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4866)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2547)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowPos(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.SetWindowPos(Widget.java:1482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBoundsInPixels(Composite.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:3203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.layout(FillLayout.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4866)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2547)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5115)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowPos(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.SetWindowPos(Widget.java:1482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBoundsInPixels(Composite.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3284)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:3280)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolderLayout.layout(CTabFolderLayout.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4866)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2547)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5115)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.EndDeferWindowPos(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.resizeChildren(Composite.java:1027)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.resizeChildren(Composite.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setResizeChildren(Composite.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1798)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4866)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2547)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowPos(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.SetWindowPos(Widget.java:1482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBoundsInPixels(Composite.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBoundsInPixels(Control.java:3208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:3203)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.layout(FillLayout.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4866)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2547)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5115)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.EndDeferWindowPos(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.resizeChildren(Composite.java:1027)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.resizeChildren(Composite.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setResizeChildren(Composite.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setLayoutDeferred(Composite.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:4252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3809)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

My class that will render the screen:

public class UsersScreen extends MainPart {

```
    /**
     * Table with all the users
     */
    private CustomNatTable<PlatformUser> userTable;

    /**
     * Table with all the different roles
     */
    private CustomNatTable<RoleCompanyViewModel> roleTable;

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService
     */
    private EPartService partService;

    /**
     * Part of this part
     */
    private MPart part;

    /**
     * List of all the roleCompany view models
     */
    private ArrayList<RoleCompanyViewModel> roleData = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * List of all the userroles
     */
    private ArrayList<UserRole> allUserRoles;

    /**
     * UserPermissionRepository repository to search for the user permissions
     */
    private UserPermissionRepository userPermissionrepo;

    /**
     * Parent composite of the userTable
     */
    private Composite userComposite;

    /**
     * Parent composite of the roleTable
     */
    private Composite roleComposite;

    private IEclipseContext context;

    /**
     * Creates the components and place it on the screen
     * 
     * @param parent
     *            Parent composite where the components need to be write on
     * @param application
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication
     * @param service
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService
     * @param partService
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService
     * @param context
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext
     * @param currentPart
     *            MPart of the UserScreen
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent, MApplication application, EModelService service,
            EPartService partService, final IEclipseContext context, MPart currentPart) {

        this.userPermissionrepo = new RepositoryManager<UserPermissionRepository>()
                .getRepository(UserPermissionRepository.class.getSimpleName());

        this.application = application;
        this.service = service;
        this.partService = partService;
        this.part = currentPart;
        this.context = context;

        FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        ScrolledForm form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
        form.setText("User Management");
        Composite body = form.getBody();
        toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(body);
        form.getBody().setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        Composite container = new Composite(body, SWT.NONE);
        container.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Section userSection = toolkit.createSection(container, Section.TITLE_BAR);
        //userSection.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(userSection);
        userSection.setText("Users");

        Section roleSection = toolkit.createSection(container, Section.TITLE_BAR);
        //roleSection.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 2));
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(roleSection);
        roleSection.setText("Roles");

        userComposite = toolkit.createComposite(userSection);
        roleComposite = toolkit.createComposite(roleSection);

        userComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        roleComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        userSection.setClient(userComposite);
        roleSection.setClient(roleComposite);

        showToolItems();

        createUserTable(userComposite, context);

        createRoleTable(roleComposite, context);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the role table on the parent composite
     * 
     * @param roleTableComposite
     *            Composite where the table must be on
     * @param context
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext
     */
    private void createRoleTable(Composite roleTableComposite, final IEclipseContext context) {

        ArrayList<NATColumnDefinition> roleDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();

        NATColumnDefinition assigned = new NATColumnDefinition("on");
        assigned.setLabel("Assigned");
        assigned.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        assigned.setColumnWidth(60);
        assigned.setData(NATColumnDefinition.DataType.BOOLEAN_COLUMN_LABEL);

        if (!connectionClosed && userPermissionrepo.containsPermission("AssignRole")) {
            assigned.setEditor(NATColumnDefinition.EditorType.BOOLEAN_EDITOR_COLUMN_LABEL);
        }

        NATColumnDefinition roleName = new NATColumnDefinition("name");
        roleName.setLabel("Name");
        roleName.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        roleName.setColumnWidth(120);

        NATColumnDefinition description = new NATColumnDefinition("description");
        description.setLabel("Description");
        description.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        description.setColumnWidth(240);

        roleDefinitions.add(assigned);
        roleDefinitions.add(roleName);
        roleDefinitions.add(description);

        roleTable = new CustomNatTable<>(roleDefinitions, roleTableComposite);
        roleTableComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        roleTable.showFilterRow(true);
        roleTable.setSortEnabled(true);
        roleTable.showHeaderGroups(false);
        roleTable.showHeaderGroupGroups(false);
        roleTable.expandTree(true);

        roleTable.treeFormat(new TreeFormat<RoleCompanyViewModel>(new Comparator<RoleCompanyViewModel>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(RoleCompanyViewModel obj1, RoleCompanyViewModel obj2) {

                if (obj1.getCompanyId() != null && obj2.getCompanyId() != null) {
                    return obj1.getCompanyId().compareTo(obj2.getCompanyId());
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }));

        roleTable.generate();

        roleTable.addMoficationListener(new IModificationListener<RoleCompanyViewModel>() {

            @Override
            public void objectModified(RoleCompanyViewModel changedObject, RoleCompanyViewModel originalObject) {

                PlatformUser user = userTable.getSelectedItem();

                if (changedObject.getChildren().size() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<RoleCompanyViewModel> userRoles = (ArrayList<RoleCompanyViewModel>) changedObject
                            .getChildren();

                    for (RoleCompanyViewModel viewModel : userRoles) {
                        UserRole role = new UserRole();
                        role.setPlatformUser(user);
                        role.setCompany(viewModel.getCompanyObject());
                        role.setRole(viewModel.getRoleObject());

                        if (viewModel.isOn()) {
                            SendInsertHandler<UserRole> handler = new SendInsertHandler<>();
                            handler.execute(role, context, UserRole.class.getSimpleName(), "UserManagement", part);
                        } else {
                            SendRemoveHandle<UserRole> handler = new SendRemoveHandle<>();
                            handler.execute(role, context, UserRole.class.getSimpleName(), "UserManagement", part);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    UserRole role = new UserRole();
                    role.setPlatformUser(user);
                    role.setCompany(changedObject.getCompanyObject());
                    role.setRole(changedObject.getRoleObject());

                    if (changedObject.isOn()) {
                        SendInsertHandler<UserRole> handler = new SendInsertHandler<>();
                        handler.execute(role, context, UserRole.class.getSimpleName(), "UserManagement", part);
                    } else {
                        SendRemoveHandle<UserRole> handler = new SendRemoveHandle<>();
                        handler.execute(role, context, UserRole.class.getSimpleName(), "UserManagement", part);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        updateRoleTable(null, null);

    }

    /**
     * Creates the user table on the parent composite
     * 
     * @param userTableComposite
     *            Composite where the table must be on
     * @param context
     * @see org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext
     */
    private void createUserTable(Composite userTableComposite, final IEclipseContext context) {
        ArrayList<NATColumnDefinition> userColumnDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();

        NATColumnDefinition userName = new NATColumnDefinition("userName");
        userName.setLabel("User name");
        userName.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        userName.setColumnWidth(120);

        NATColumnDefinition firstName = new NATColumnDefinition("firstName");
        firstName.setLabel("First name");
        firstName.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        firstName.setColumnWidth(120);

        NATColumnDefinition lastName = new NATColumnDefinition("lastName");
        lastName.setLabel("Last name");
        lastName.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        lastName.setColumnWidth(120);

        NATColumnDefinition domain = new NATColumnDefinition("domain");
        domain.setLabel("Domain");
        domain.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        domain.setColumnWidth(60);

        NATColumnDefinition active = new NATColumnDefinition("active");
        active.setLabel("Active");
        active.setAligment(Alignment.COLUMN_CENTER_LABEL);
        active.setColumnWidth(60);
        active.setDataType(NATColumnDefinition.DataType.BOOLEAN_COLUMN_LABEL);

        if (!connectionClosed && userPermissionrepo.containsPermission("DeactivateUser")) {
            active.setEditor(NATColumnDefinition.EditorType.BOOLEAN_EDITOR_COLUMN_LABEL);
        }

        if (!connectionClosed && userPermissionrepo.containsPermission("EditUser")) {
            firstName.setEditor(NATColumnDefinition.EditorType.TEXT_EDITOR_COLUMN_LABEL);
            lastName.setEditor(NATColumnDefinition.EditorType.TEXT_EDITOR_COLUMN_LABEL);
        }

        userColumnDefinitions.add(userName);
        userColumnDefinitions.add(firstName);
        userColumnDefinitions.add(lastName);
        userColumnDefinitions.add(domain);
        userColumnDefinitions.add(active);

        userTable = new CustomNatTable<>(userColumnDefinitions, userTableComposite);
        // userTableComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        userTable.showFilterRow(true);
        userTable.setSortEnabled(true);
        userTable.showHeaderGroups(false);
        userTable.showHeaderGroupGroups(false);
        userTable.generate();

        userTable.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<PlatformUser>() {

            @Override
            public void itemSelected(PlatformUser item) {

                checkSelection(item);
                roleTable.refresh(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void gridSelectionChanged(GridSelection selection) {

            }
        });
        userTable.addMoficationListener(new IModificationListener<PlatformUser>() {

            @Override
            public void objectModified(PlatformUser changedObject, PlatformUser originalObject) {
                SendUpdateHandler<PlatformUser> handler = new SendUpdateHandler<>();

                handler.execute(changedObject, originalObject, context, changedObject.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "UserManagement", partService.getActivePart());
            }
        });

        userDataChanged(null);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the close action from the window
     */
    @PreDestroy
    public void windowClose() {

        CloseScreenHandler handler = new CloseScreenHandler();
        handler.execute("UserManagement", part);

        MDirectToolItem addUser = getToolItem(application, service, "addUserToolItem");
        addUser.setToBeRendered(false);
        addUser.setVisible(false);
    }

    /**
     * Will be called when some data has been changed in the RoleRepository
     * 
     * @param repo
     *            Platform user repository
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void roleDataChanged(@UIEventTopic("RoleRepository") RoleRepository repo) {

        updateRoleTable(repo, null);
    }

    /**
     * Will be called when some data has been changed in the
     * PlatformUserRepository
     * 
     * @param data
     *            Platform user repository
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void userDataChanged(@UIEventTopic("PlatformUserRepository") PlatformUserRepository data) {

        if(data == null)
        {
            RepositoryManager<PlatformUserRepository> manager = new RepositoryManager<PlatformUserRepository>();

            data = manager.getRepository(PlatformUserRepository.class.getSimpleName());

        }
        userTable.setItems(data.getAllData());
        userTable.refresh(true);
    }

    /**
     * Will be called when some data has been changed in the CompanyRepository.
     * 
     * @param repo
     *            Company repository
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void companyDataChanged(@UIEventTopic("CompanyRepository") CompanyRepository repo) {
        updateRoleTable(null, repo);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the change of UserRoleRepository object
     * 
     * @param repo
     *            UserRoleRepository object that has been changed
     */
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void userRolDataChanged(@UIEventTopic("UserRoleRepository") UserRoleRepository repo) {
        allUserRoles = repo.getAllData();

        PlatformUser selectedUser = userTable.getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedUser != null)
        {
            checkSelection(selectedUser);
            roleTable.refresh(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Something inside one of your `Section`s probably, but there is too much code here and too many missing classes to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Some old code was still in my class to draw the a Nattable.
The code was a GridFactory that places the table on a grid. Removed this line fixed my problem.